# Rule activation order while using auto-focus

Tags: drools

I have some doubts regarding the order in which the rules are activated if they are given the attribute `auto-focus`.

For example, if I have the following rule-file:

```
rule "Rule1" salience 2
agenda-group "group1"
auto-focus
    when
        ...
    then
        ...
end

rule "Rule2" salience 1
agenda-group "group2"
auto-focus
    when
        ...
    then
        ...
end
```

and I pass a fact which activates both the rules, I observe that the agenda groups are stacked in the order:

```
group2
group1
```

which means that `Rule2` is executed first.

Now if I reverse the order of the rules:

```
rule "Rule2" salience 1
agenda-group "group2"
auto-focus
    when
        ...
    then
        ...
end

rule "Rule1" salience 2
agenda-group "group1"
auto-focus
    when
        ...
    then
        ...
end
```

I observe that `Rule1` is fired first now.

Does this mean that salience does not affect the order of activations in case of `auto-focus`, but instead it depends on the order in which the rules are written in the rules file ?

I went through [this discussion](http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/suprises-when-using-auto-focus-with-salience-or-lock-on-active-td101839.html) regarding this topic but did not find satisfactory answers.

If the behavior I described is correct, is it documented anywhere ?

I am using Drools 6.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the rule attributes are ad-hoc extensions that have been invented to allow rule authors to reduce the logic of their rules. You should be very careful whenever a SW feature announces "auto(matic)".

If an activation (which is *not* the same as executing) sets an agenda-group, then salience will only decide *within* that group. Salience, on the other hand, does not govern the evaluation order.

Remove the auto-focus and the agenda-group if you need to handle the decision between two or more agenda-groups by a rule. Call e.g.

```
drools.setFocus( "group1" );
```

on the right hand side of the rule doing the selection.